# Constructing, not selecting, XSL node set variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, msxsl

I wish to construct an XSL node set variable using a contained for-each loop. It is important that the constructed node set is the original (a selected) node set, not a copy.

Here is a much simplified version of my problem (which could of course be solved with a select, but that's not the point of the question). I've used the <name> node to test that the constructed node set variable is in fact in the original tree and not a copy.

XSL version 1.0, processor is msxsl.

Non-working XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="entries">
        <xsl:for-each select="//entry">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="entryNodes" select="msxsl:node-set($entries)"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$entryNodes">
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <name>X</name>
    <entry>1</entry>
    <entry>2</entry>
</root>
```

Wanted output:

```
X1X2
```

Actual output:

```
12
```

Of course the (or a) problem is the copy-of, but I can't work out a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a "way around it" in XSLT 1.0 - it's exactly how this is supposed to work.  When you have a variable that is declared with content rather than with a `select` then that content is a result tree fragment consisting of newly-created nodes (even if those nodes are a copy of nodes from the original tree).  If you want to refer to the original nodes attached to the original tree then you *must* declare the variable using `select`.  A better question would be to detail the actual problem and ask how you could write a suitable `select` expression to find the nodes you want without needing to use `for-each` - most uses of `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose` can be replaced with suitably constructed predicates, maybe involving judicious use of `xsl:key`, etc.

---

In XSLT 2.0 it's much more flexible.  There's no distinction between node sets and result tree fragments, and the content of an `xsl:variable` is treated as a generic "sequence constructor" which can give you new nodes if you construct or copy them:

```
<xsl:variable name="example" as="node()*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//entry" />
</xsl:variable>
```

or the original nodes if you use `xsl:sequence`:

```
<xsl:variable name="example" as="node()*">
  <xsl:sequence select="//entry" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to construct an XSL node set variable using a contained
>   for-each loop.

I have no idea what that means.

> It is important that the constructed node set is the original (a
>   selected) node set, not a copy.

This part I *think* I understand a little better.  It seems you need to replace:

```
<xsl:variable name="entries">
    <xsl:for-each select="//entry">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

with:

```
<xsl:variable name="entries" select="//entry"/>
```

or, preferably:

```
<xsl:variable name="entries" select="root/entry"/>
```

The resulting variable is a **node-set** of the original `entry` nodes, so you can do simply:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$entries">
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to get your expected result.

Of course, you could do the same thing by operating directly on the original nodes, in their original context - without requiring the variable.

---

***In response to the comments you've made:***

We obviously need a better example here, but I think I am getting a vague idea of where you want to go with this. But there are a few things you must understand first:

**1.**
In order to construct a variable which contains a node-set of nodes in their original context, you **must** use `select`. This does not place any limits whatsoever on what you can select. You can do your selection all at once, or in stages, or even in a loop (here I mean a real loop). You can combine the intermediate selections you have made in any way sets can be combined: union, intersection, or difference. But you must use `select` in all these steps, otherwise you will end up with a set of new nodes, no longer having the context they did in the source tree.

IOW, the only difference between using `copy` and `select` is that the former creates new nodes, which is precisely what you wish to avoid.

**2.**
`xsl:for-each` is not a loop. It has no hierarchy or chronology. All the nodes are processed in parallel, and there is no way to use the result of previous iteration in the current one - because no iteration is "previous" to another.

If you try to use `xsl:for-each` in order to add each of n processed nodes to a pre-existing node-set, you will end up with n results, each containing the pre-existing node-set joined with *one* of the processed nodes.

**3.**
I think you'll find the XPath language is quite powerful, and allows you to select the nodes you want without having to go through the complicated loops you hint at.

Comment: Hi Michael. Sorry if my phrasing was confusing, maybe I was being too brief. I meant, "I wish to construct an XSL variable which contains a node set, using a for-each loop in the variable element, not by using a select attribute." As mentioned later, "could of course be solved with a select, but that's not the point of the question". Your solution here uses a select attribute. I apologise that the question was not clear.

Comment: Or "I wish to construct an XSL variable which contains a node set, using a for-each loop in the variable definition node's content, not by using its select attribute, but having the same effect as if the select attribute were instead used." I hope the terminology there is more correct.

Comment: @CaptainNormal I have added a few notes to my answer, based on the comments you've made on this and the other answers; they were too long to put in a comment.

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with an example similar to my real problem. My real problem involves a "complicated" algorithm involving named template calls to construct a variable containing a node set, and passing this variable to several other templates, and somewhere at the end of the chain I need to find an element in a completely unrelated part of the XML and compare it to a related element in a different XML file. Your item #1 may work, if I can put the select inside a loop. The example will be sufficiently unrelated to this question that I'll post it separately; I'll post a link to it here.

Comment: @CaptainNormal Keep in mind that there are other possible approaches, too. For example, instead of collecting the actual nodes in their original context, you could collect their unique ids - thus being able to link back to the source node, in its original context, at any time.

Comment: I've posted a less simplified version of my problem here. I'm very curious if you can find a way to use select for this complicated case, or if there is indeed a completly different approach I have not thought of. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673283/complex-selection-of-xsl-1-0-node-set

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you showed us a problem that can't be trivially solved in XSLT 1.0. You can't solve your problem the way you are asking for: there is no equivalent of xsl:sequence in XSLT 1.0. But the problem you have shown us can be solved without such a construct. So please explain why you need what you are asking for.

Comment: Hi Michael. The selection of nodes in my real-life case is complicated and involves template calls where one would normally use [] inside the select. If there is no solution to my problem as stated in my simple example, I'll first try to find a workaround myself before troubling you people about it, then if it's too ugly for this world I'll post again to see if someone can improve upon it. I was hoping there was something fundamental I was missing in my understanding, but I suspect after reading the above answers it's instead a fundamental limitation/characteristic of XML 1.0.