# Complex selection of XSL 1.0 node set

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

(This question is a less simplified version of my problem. The more simplified version which was already answered can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631847/constructing-not-selecting-xsl-node-set-variable). I'm posting this more complicated question due to a comment by michael.hor257k who suggested that there may be an alternative approach that could solve it - possibly using select in a loop, or possibly a completely different approach.)

I'd like to process an XML file, over whose format I have no control, to generate C++ code. I need to process functions defined in XML in several different ways to produce different parts of the code. As part of this I need to select a subset of function parameters that match a complicated criteria and pass this selection to several named templates; the named templates need to be able to access the original document.

This example creates a complex selection of C++ function parameters that do not have constant values (ie the same min and max), where the min and max may be decimal or hexadecimal, using the "GenerateNonFixedParameters" template. The parameters refer to enumerations which are located elsewhere in the document, and these definitions are referenced by the named template call "ListParameterValues".

There are two problems.

1. The creation of the variable "nonFixedParameters" does not use select. I cannot work out how to use select for such a complicated case (XSL 1.0), but maybe there is a way.
2. A copy of the nodes does not suffice, as the "ListParameterValues" template as it currently stands needs to operate on an original set of nodes from the document.

Example XSL with the locations of these two problems marked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//function">
            <!-- 1. This does not use 'select' therefore it does not work. This is XSL 1.0 so as="node()*" cannot be used. -->
            <xsl:variable name="nonFixedParameters">
                <xsl:call-template name="GenerateNonFixedParameters"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="ListParameterValues">
                <xsl:with-param name="parameters" select="$nonFixedParameters"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ListParameterValues">
        <xsl:param name="parameters"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$parameters">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="min">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@min" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="max">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@max" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- 2. This must be executed in the context of a document node, therefore this does not work. -->
            <xsl:for-each select="//enum[@name=current()/@enum]/value">
                <xsl:if test="@val &gt;= $min and @val &lt;= $max">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GenerateNonFixedParameters">
        <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
            <xsl:variable name="min">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@min" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="max">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@max" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$min != $max">
                <!-- Here a copy is clearly the wrong approach! -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="HexToNum">
        <xsl:param name="hex" />
        <xsl:param name="num" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="msb" select="translate(substring($hex, 1, 1), 'abcdef', 'ABCDEF')"/>
        <xsl:param name="value" select="string-length(substring-before('0123456789ABCDEF', $msb))"/>
        <xsl:param name="result" select="16 * $num + $value"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($hex) &gt; 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="HexToNum">
                <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring($hex, 2)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$result"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($hex) &lt;= 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ToNum">
        <xsl:param name="hexOrNum" />
        <xsl:if test="starts-with($hexOrNum, '0x')">
            <xsl:call-template name="HexToNum">
                <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring-after($hexOrNum, '0x')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(starts-with($hexOrNum, '0x'))">
            <xsl:value-of select="$hexOrNum"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Simple XML to feed the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <dictionary>
        <enum name="EnumName">
            <value name="firstValue" val="1" />
            <value name="secondValue" val="2" />
            <value name="thirdValue" val="3" />
            <value name="forthValue" val="4" />
            <value name="fifthValue" val="5" />
        </enum>
    </dictionary>
    <function name="FunctionOne">
        <parameter name="p1" type="enum" enum="EnumName" min="2" max="0x4"/>
        <parameter name="p2" type="enum" enum="EnumName" min="0x03" max="3"/>
    </function>
</body>
```

Wanted output. Note that p1 has all names within [min..max] listed, but p2 has none listed because min and max have the same value.

```
p1[secondValue thirdValue forthValue ] p2[]
```

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/94hvTzi

Comment: If you need to construct a result tree fragment but then process it as a node set then XSLT 1.0 processors do support an extension function for that. And of course you can store the main document in a variable or parameter if you need to compare node from different document (like an intermediary one and the main input one). So http://xsltransform.net/94hvTzi/1 should give you some idea on which XSLT techniques help dealing with result tree fragments and with different documents. I post this as a comment as it is a code/link only suggestion.

Comment: If you are using MSXML then `exsl:node-set` is not supported by you can use `<xsl:for-each xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" select="ms:node-set($parameters)/parameter">` instead.

Comment: Looking at the currently XSLT, you call the template `GenerateNonFixedParamaters` in which you iterate over the `parameter` elements. You then take the results of this and pass the selected parameters to `ListParameterValues` where you iterate over the selected parameters and recalculate the same "min" and "max" values which were calculated in `GenerateNonFixedParamaters`. Perhaps you could combine the two templates into one, so you instantly output the parameter as soon as you calculate the min and max; For example http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFn

Comment: @Tim: I mentioned in the question that I need to process the "pass this selection to several named templates". If it were just one template, it could be combined, but in my case I have quite a few templates - and my real `GenerateNonFixedParamaters` template is much more complicated so I do not want to repeat it.

Comment: @Martin: The first bit of your comment I knew about (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631847/constructing-not-selecting-xsl-node-set-variable)), but the use of a global variable to store the main document is an obvious and clean solution to my problem that I just simply did not think of. Maybe you want to put your comment into an answer?

Comment: Using "node-set" as suggested by Martin Honnen's is almost certainly the best approach then. A less elegant alternative would be to return the "@name" of the parameters, and use the string function `contains` to select the parameters with the matching name. See this: http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJp/1

Comment: @Tim: Also a good approach, using a delimited list to perform the select. I'd be tempted to use it, but in my real case the thing represented by `ListParameterValues` needs access to the original node or a copy, as well as other nodes within the document. But thank you for showing me another useful technique!

Comment: @CaptainNormal, I posted the suggestions in an answer so the the question can be resolved properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your stylesheet can be made to work with XSLT 1.0 if you use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` to convert your result tree fragment into a node-set and if you store the root node of the primary input tree into a global variable or parameter as then you will be able to compare nodes in your primary input document to nodes of the newly constructed, temporary tree.

Based on these suggestions the code would look like

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//function">
            <!-- 1. Using exsl:node-set or similar you can convert that result tree fragment into a node set to process it further -->
            <xsl:variable name="nonFixedParameters">
                <xsl:call-template name="GenerateNonFixedParameters"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="ListParameterValues">
                <xsl:with-param name="parameters" select="$nonFixedParameters"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ListParameterValues">
        <xsl:param name="parameters"/>
        <!-- <xsl:for-each xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" select="ms:node-set($parameters)/parameter"> for MSXML or XslTransform -->
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($parameters)/parameter">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="min">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@min" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="max">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@max" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- 2. This must be executed in the context of a document node, therefore using the global variable works. -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$main-root//enum[@name=current()/@enum]/value">
                <xsl:if test="@val &gt;= $min and @val &lt;= $max">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GenerateNonFixedParameters">
        <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
            <xsl:variable name="min">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@min" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="max">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@max" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$min != $max">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="HexToNum">
        <xsl:param name="hex" />
        <xsl:param name="num" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="msb" select="translate(substring($hex, 1, 1), 'abcdef', 'ABCDEF')"/>
        <xsl:param name="value" select="string-length(substring-before('0123456789ABCDEF', $msb))"/>
        <xsl:param name="result" select="16 * $num + $value"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($hex) &gt; 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="HexToNum">
                <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring($hex, 2)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$result"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($hex) &lt;= 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ToNum">
        <xsl:param name="hexOrNum" />
        <xsl:if test="starts-with($hexOrNum, '0x')">
            <xsl:call-template name="HexToNum">
                <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring-after($hexOrNum, '0x')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(starts-with($hexOrNum, '0x'))">
            <xsl:value-of select="$hexOrNum"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The example is online at http://xsltransform.net/94hvTzi/1.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show a different approach that actually selects and processes the original nodes, in their original context - as was discussed in the previous thread. Consider:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="body/function">
        <xsl:call-template name="select-parameters">
            <xsl:with-param name="input-set" select="parameter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="select-parameters">
    <xsl:param name="input-set"/>
    <xsl:param name="output-set" select="dummy-node"/>
    <xsl:variable name="current-node" select="$input-set[1]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$current-node">
            <xsl:variable name="min">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="$current-node/@min" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="max">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="$current-node/@max" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="select-parameters">
                <xsl:with-param name="input-set" select="$input-set[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="output-set" select="$output-set | $current-node[$min != $max]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- call a template to process the currently selected node-set -->
            <xsl:call-template name="process-parameters">
                <xsl:with-param name="input-set" select="$output-set"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <!-- call more templates here, if required -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="enum-by-name" match="enum" use="@name" />

<xsl:template name="process-parameters">
    <xsl:param name="input-set"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$input-set">
            <xsl:variable name="min">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@min" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="max">
                <xsl:call-template name="ToNum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hexOrNum" select="@max" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, '[')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('enum-by-name', @enum)/value[@val &gt;= $min and @val &lt;= $max]">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="HexToNum">
    <xsl:param name="hex" />
    <xsl:param name="num" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="msb" select="translate(substring($hex, 1, 1), 'abcdef', 'ABCDEF')"/>
    <xsl:param name="value" select="string-length(substring-before('0123456789ABCDEF', $msb))"/>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="16 * $num + $value"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($hex) &gt; 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="HexToNum">
            <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring($hex, 2)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$result"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($hex) &lt;= 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ToNum">
    <xsl:param name="hexOrNum" />
    <xsl:if test="starts-with($hexOrNum, '0x')">
        <xsl:call-template name="HexToNum">
            <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring-after($hexOrNum, '0x')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(starts-with($hexOrNum, '0x'))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$hexOrNum"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem with this approach is that it works exactly as advertised; the nodes selected at the end of the selecting processes are the original, unmodified parameters. As a result, they still carry the mixture of decimal and hexadecimal values, and you must convert these again when processing the selected set.

So it might well be more worthwhile to pre-process the parameters by normalizing the values to a common base, then use the result (converted to a node-set) for the rest of the processing. I wouldn't spend so much effort at *selecting* those that meet the criteria - because once the values are consistent, the selection becomes trivial. If you like, I will post a demo showing that.

Comment: You know, I've been extremely impressed with the quality of the answers by you and a couple of others, here and to other questions! This is an excellent technique to create a node set with XSL 1.0, recursive use of select. For my case I can't use it easily because the resulting variable is deep in the loop, not at the top - though admittedly I did not state this as a requirement in my question. The templates I need to pass the node set to are called from several different places. But I've learned something useful from this answer and hope others will too!